# Regular Expression - Find Lottery numbers

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I was hoping for some regular expression guidance if possible as I am rubbish at them :(

I have scanned a lottery ticket to text and I am trying to pull out the lottery numbers from the returned text.

Here is the string being returned:

```
"if * it • 
Including Millionaire Raffle
7618-011874089-204279   111111111111111111111111111111
Goad luck for your draw on Fri 09 Nov 12
Your numbers
Lucky Stars
A 1 8 22 37 47 48 - 03 10
B11 15 26 43 44 - 05 06
C 08 23 27 28 29 - 02 09
D06 09 21 26 29 - 01 05
E 06 07 21 22 45 - 04 05
Your raffle numbers) for your draw(s)
PRC690104 
PRC690105 
PRC690106 
PRC690107 
1DRC690108
CHECK YOUR MILLIONAIRE RAFFLE 
RESULTS ONLINE AT 
WWW.NATIONAL-LOTTERY.CO.UK
5 plays x f2.00 for 1 draw = f10.00
HUGE EUROMILLIONS JACKPOTS TO
PLAY FOR EVERY TUESDAY AND
FRIDAY! PLAY TODAY FOR THE
CHANCE TO WIN YOUR WILDEST
DREAMS!
7618-011874089-204279 035469 Term. 26048301
Fill the box to void the ticket
11111111111111111111111 1111111111111111111111111"
```

This is the image that was scanned:

[image: The ticket that was scanned]

As you can see the lottery numbers seem to always appear between "Lucky Stars" and "Your Raffle"

Can anyone suggest how to strip out the results so I get "A18223747480310","B11152643440506","C08232728290209","D06092126290105","E06072122450405" please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the text returned as one long string or as a string array? if its the latter just look for the line with stars on it, then take the next x ammount of lines until you get to the one that says *your*

Comment: Even if this is an interesting use case (at least from the upvotes you got), you should try and provide us what you've tried. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @HamZa thanks. that's very generous of you. So far I have spent all yesterday and awake all night last night trying to work out a strategy. I think I can get close by grabbing everything between "Lucky Stars" and "Your raffle" but from there im stumped.

Comment: trevor, if your already there just split on space and - and then use stringsplitoptions

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I was more talking in terms of code. I've seen too many questions of the type "give me the code to solve this problem". If you don't try anything out and just get the code ready made you will never learn. If you provided something I would gladely help you out in constructing a regex, and maybe even pointing out what went wrong with your regex. - A process of learning -

Comment: @Sayse so would I grab the string between "Lucky Stars" and "Your raffle" then remove all spaces and "-" then cut the string every time I see a capital letter? eg "A","B","C"?

Comment: @HamZa sorry. you are correct. it's just im struggling on what "strategy" to use, let alone get close to writing the regex yet.

Comment: Well, first of all show the command you used to scan-to text that image. so far you've only provided the image to reproduce that. Next thing missing is the code you've got so far. It's also missing. Please create an example that is possible to reproduce so your question can be actually answered. A strategy is highly dependent on the subject which you so far only describe by words, however it's much more precise in code. Point in case is that there is variance with every OCR'ing done, so building a regex supporting an isolated case is - hmm - limited? (yes I think that's the right word).

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `Regex` and `string.Split` would be simpler and more efficient:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(?s)(?<=Lucky Stars).+?(?=Your raffle numbers)");
string[] yourNumbers = Regex.Replace(reg.Match("inputString").Value,"[ -]", "")
                            .Split(new char[]{'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I didn't notice your expected result, just updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to keep things simple: Each lottery number consists of one of the letters `A` to `E` followed by exactly 14 digits, each of which may have multiple whitespace and/or hyphen (-) characters in between.

So here's a regular expression to extract each lottery number:

```
[A-E]([\s-]*\d){14}
```

**Visualisation:** (from [Debuggex demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/zP_BXMxXaISX8BHq))

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Then get the results you want by replacing all spaces and dashes with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since the results have leading 0 (for example, 08 for 8), the easy way would be split every 2-digit. No Regular Expression required.

Comment: Have you looked at the output? There would have to be more interpretation than that because the lottery ticket shows the numbers in a mono-spaced font, the resulting text representation can sometimes put in extra spaces next to thin characters that aren't there.

Comment: @ColinMackay, Yes, I have, for example, 'A 1 8 22 37 47 48 - 03 10', trim all spaces and '-', remove the first character. It turns to 18223747480310, and then split to 18, 22, 37, 47, 48, 03, 10. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This pair of regular expresions should work for a case you showed us.

```
/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Sun, Aug 25, 2013, 12:55:52 PM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.4334, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  Match expression but don't capture it. [Lucky Stars\r\n]
///      Lucky Stars\r\n
///          Lucky
///          Space
///          Stars
///          Carriage return
///          New line
///  [Numbers]: A named capture group. [.*\r\n], exactly 5 repetitions
///      .*\r\n
///          Any character, any number of repetitions
///          Carriage return
///          New line
///  
///
/// </summary>
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "(?:Lucky Stars\\r\\n)(?<Numbers>.*\\r\\n){5}",
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );


public static Regex replaceRegex = new Regex(
      "(\\s-.*\r\n)",
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

And the code for numbers retrieval could be as following:

```
var InputText = @"Lucky Stars
A 1 8 22 37 47 48 - 03 10
B11 15 26 43 44 - 05 06
C 08 23 27 28 29 - 02 09
D06 09 21 26 29 - 01 05
E 06 07 21 22 45 - 04 05
Your raffle numbers";

Match m = regex.Match(InputText);
var numbers = m.Groups["Numbers"].Captures
    .OfType<Capture>()
    .Select(c => replaceRegex.Replace(c.Value, "").Replace(" ", ""));
```

But I doubt that using regex is the best solution in case when you are using OCR technique to get text from picture.